# android How to select multiple images from gallery and preview on gridview/framelayout

Tags: android, gridview, android-intent, imageview, android-gridview

I want to open the gallery and select multiple image. Then the selected image are preview in a gridview or framelayout. how do you select multiple photos from gallery and save that in imageview array. and everytime you choose again it stack.

I tried

Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

but it just select one image

anybody know how to do this?

Comment: And whats the issue you're having?

Answer (score 0):

Refer this github project, you will find it useful and would satisfy your requirement.

https://github.com/derosa/MultiImageChooser

Also this may be useful :

https://github.com/luminousman/MultipleImagePick